# Binary stream transfer across multiple socket connections

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, websocket, socket.io

I have a use case where I need to take input from browser pass it to my node server over a socket, this input is then send to a third party website for processing again over socket. The result received from the third party website needs to be sent back to browser.

**node server**

```js
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var socketIO = require('socket.io'),
  server, io;
var thirdPartSocketClient = require('socket.io-client');

//Custom imports
var thirdParty = require('./ms_socket.js');

var socket = socketIO(server);
socket.on('connection', function(client) {
  var token = null;
  //Token from third party site that we should have before sending the actual info
  thirdParty.getToken(function callback(returnToken) {
    token = returnToken;
  });
  thirdPartSocketClient = thirdParty.getTranslation(token);
  client.on('audio', function(data) {
    thirdPartSocketClient.emit(data);
  });
});

server.listen(8080, function() {
  console.log('Open http://localhost:8080 in your browser');
});
```

**ms_socket.js**

```js
//Exported function making a socket call to third party service
var exports = module.exports = {};
var request = require('request');
var wsClient = require('socket.io-client');
var fs = require('fs');

exports.getToken = function(callback) {
  //send back the token
}

exports.getTranslation = function(accessToken) {

  var ws = new wsClient(thirdPartySocketURL);

  // event for connection failure
  ws.on('connectFailed', function(error) {
    console.log('Initial connection failed: ' + error.toString());
  });

  // event for connection succeed
  ws.on('connect', function(connection) {
    console.log('Websocket client connected');

    // process message that is returned
    //processMessage would process the incoming msg from third party service
    connection.on('message', processMessage);

    connection.on('close', function(reasonCode, description) {
      console.log('Connection closed: ' + reasonCode);
    });

    // print out the error
    connection.on('error', function(error) {
      console.log('Connection error: ' + error.toString());
    });

  });
  // connect to the service
  ws.connect(thirdPartySocketURL, null, null, {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + accessToken
  });
  return ws;
}; //End of export function
```

I am able to receive the data from browser, make a connection to third party service (can see the socket connection) and emit the data. however I am unable to receive the reply back from the third part service. 
Is it because node is not listening to my socket events of thirdparty ?
Not sure exactly why its not working. 
I save the data locally on the server, read the file and then send it, then I get a response back from the service.

If this is not a "right" design can you please suggest a good way, should I be using message queues (if yes, feel free to recommend one)

Thanks

Comment: Is the above second code snippet the code of `./ms_socket.js` file ? Can you show the third party website code?

Comment: Yes the second code snippet is from ms_socket.js file.

Comment: You export two functions: `getToken` and `getTranslation`. But the server uses `thirdParty.getToken` and `thirdParty.sendData`.. and in a strange way: `var thirdPartSocketClient = require('socket.io-client');  thirdPartSocketClient = thirdParty.sendData(token); thirdPartSocketClient.emit(data);` - just trying to understand your code ;)

Comment: Oops, missed in making the function name clearer for stackoverflow. So gettoken gets the token, gettranslation connects to the third party service and returns a socket. This socket is then used by server.js to emit the incoming data to thirdparty service.

Comment: Shouldn't it rather be: `thirdPartSocketClient.emit('some event', data);` instead of `thirdPartSocketClient.emit(data);` ? What is `data` here?

Comment: emit should also work. data is binary audio received from the browser.

Comment: The code is difficult to follow, but I would expect it to follow a simple pattern: `client.pipe(thirdPartyStream(function(result) { console.log(result); }))`. You want to upload the file to your node server and directly stream it to the third party server without using a temporary file.

Comment: Emit will not work without the eventName argument - how can you register a listener to that event?

Comment: Sorry I probably left out few things to keep things simple. I getting streamed audio data from browser over a socket. This is the `client.on('audio', function(data)` in server.js. I need to send this `data` to third party server for processing. This is present in the ms_socket.js. I do the basic handshake with the server in getToken and getTranslation methods, but do the actual sending using `thirdPartSocketClient.emit(data)`. Please let me know if this helps

Comment: But `thirdPartSocketClient.emit' does not send data but emits events. And an event needs an eventName. Can you show the third party server code?

Comment: Found out what the problem was - I was doing all communication using socket.io however the third party service was expecting it in websockets. Once I fixed that things work. thanks for brainstorming that got me looking at the problem from a different angle.